# Cannot execute binary file: Exec format error, when trying to execute a x86 assembly NASM program

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, assembly, nasm

My main OS is Windows 10, but I've got Linux with Ubuntu installed (WSL). There I am trying to run a simple x86 NASM assembly program (called "asem.asm") following [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/IGo2ldg2Mp0?si=z0y4_9jp0t8S6BYr&t=366), where everything works. Here's the code:

```
section .data

section .text
global _start

_start:
      MOV eax, 1
      MOV ebx, 1
      INT 80h
```

My system type:

```
Linux DESKTOP-AHS9L1H 4.4.0-19041-Microsoft #3570-Microsoft Fri Sep 29 17:00:00 PST 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The commands, which I do in the current repository:

```
nasm -f elf -o asem.o asem.asm 
ld -m elf_i386 -o asem asem.o 
./asem
```

The first two create two files: asem.o and asem, which is all like in the tutorial, but the last one results in an error output:

```
-bash: ./asem: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Is the method, which I'm using, even valid for my situation? If yes, then how do I run the file?
I now that the error in the architectures and I've tried a lot of different ones (elf32, elf64, elfx32), but none of them work.
A promising one was (although I'm trying to run a x86 and this uses elf64):

```
nasm -f elf64 asem.asm -o asem.o    
ld -o asem asem.o -m elf_x86_64 
./asem
```

But it results in a:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: You're probably using WSL1, which is like real Linux without `CONFIG_IA32_EMULATION`, which would explain both symptoms ([What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46087730)).  See the linked duplicate for how to make sure your WSL is really a WSL2 install.

Comment: On my system the command `uname -a`  reports `Linux VITSOFT 5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Fri Jan 27 02:56:13 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` and your example works fine.

Comment: Everything works now, the problem was (thanks to the first comment), that I had WSL1 from 2021. I just upgraded it